How does GitHub identify contributors?
I'm migrating TFS repositories that use a Git source control over to GitHub and noticed that the contributors of the TFS repository get added to the list of contributors on GitHub. However, the contributors are not listed as collaborators. I presume it's because of the .git folder that has that metadata about contributors and GitHub recognizes that the contributors' emails match to those of my members in my organization. Not seeing any clear documentation though.
Also, how can I get those contributors to be automatically added to the collaborator list in GitHub upon migration? (i.e. after a git clone and git push of all the contents from TFS to GitHub)

Contributors are determined by the commit history, whereas collaborators are people given access to the repo by its owner/administrators. So no, you definitely don't want to automate any connection between these two lists: if you accept to merge someone's pull request, that makes them a contributor, but it should not make them a collaborator unless you then want to grant them write permission too.

There is some documentation about contributors for a project here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-a-projects-contributors

And this documents how to add collaborators to a personal repo and how to manage collaborators on a team repo.
